# Trying to get input of a character and a string in an overloaded function

Tags: c++

> Write a program that provides two overloaded functions named ... `mycount(...)`.This function either computes the difference between the second and ﬁrst parameter (in this order) if integers are passed or counts the number of occurrences of a character if a character and a string are passed. Forexample, `mycount(7, 3)`should return −4 and `mycount(’i’, "this is a string")` should return 3. In case of no occurrence 0 should be returned. Write a simple `main()` function that demonstrates the above described behavior for both functions.

My problem is just with taking the string from the keyboard. The function that calculates the difference is working properly. I also don't want to force the user to enter two integers first then a character and a string, I want the program to pass these variables independently of the order.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int mycount(int x, int y) {
  int difference = y - x;

  cout << "The difference is: ";
  return difference;
}
int mycount(char c, string s) {
  int i;  // loop counter
  int count = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
    if (s[i] == c) {
      count++;
      cout << "the count is: " << count << endl;
      return count;
    } else
      return 0;
  }
}

int main() {
  int x;
  int y;
  char c;
  string s;
  if (cin >> x && cin >> y) {
    cout << mycount(x, y) << endl;
  }
  if (cin >> c) {
    getline(cin, s);  // i cannot take the string from the keyboard
    cout << mycount(c, s) << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I cannot enter the string as an input, the program ends before entering a string, so just after taking the character from the keyboard.

Comment: Try to minimize your program. For example, you just mentioned that your difference function has no problem. Then why don't you remove it from the program, as it has no relation to your question.

Comment: it makes sense to show all the code.. am a new user though :)

Comment: No, It makes no sense to show unrelated code. Please provide a [mcve]. Also please format your to make it more readable for others. If your IDE/editor doesn't support code formatting you can use http://format.krzaq.cc/

Comment: Also, you might discover the bug in the process of minimizing your code. I've only glanced at it, but I suspect that the problem is in the in-between stage of your program, not in the function itself.

Comment: In your given task there isn't mentioned that the values come from user. You could create the functions and call them in your program with fixed values.

Comment: To add on to what Thomas said, when you're testing functions that you've written, you typically want as little that can go wrong in the testing framework as possible, that way when something does go wrong, you can tell that it's a problem with the functions, and not with the testing framework.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at this part of your code:

```cpp
if(cin >> c)
{
    getline(cin, s); // i cannot take the string from the keyboard
    cout << mycount(c,s) << endl;
}
```

`cin >> c` reads from stdin until it finds a whitespace character, for example a space, tab or newline symbol. Whenever it hits one of them, it stops reading, leaves them on the buffer and returns the value it found.

`getline(cin, s)` reads stdin until it finds a newline character, removes the character from the buffer and returns everything it read until that point.

So, lets say your input looks like this:

> 7
>
> 3
>
> i
>
> this is a string

`cin >> x` will read 7 and leave the newline character on the buffer.

`cin >> y` ignores the whitespace, reads 3, leaves another newline character on the buffer.

`cin >> c` ignores the whitespace, reads 'i', leaves the newline character behind.

`getline(cin, s);` will read everything that's left on the buffer until a newline character. Since the next character on the buffer is a new line, it returns an empty string.

To fix this problem, you could read and discard one character after your last cin to get rid of the new line character.

`cin.ignore()` will do just that, so your code could look something like this:

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int mycount(int x, int y) {
    int difference = y - x;

    cout << "The difference is: ";
    return difference;
}
int mycount(char c, string s) {
    int i; // loop counter
    int count = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
        if(s[i] == c) {
            count++;
            cout << "the count is: " << count << endl;
            return count;
        } else
            return 0;
    }
}

int main() {
    int x;
    int y;
    char c;
    string s;
    if(cin >> x && cin >> y) {


        cout << mycount(x, y) << endl;
    }
    if(cin >> c) {
        // Get rid of trailing newline character on the buffer
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, s);
        cout << mycount(c, s) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note:

You might want to take a look at the implementation of your `int mycount(char c, string s);` function, as it does not do what you want it to at the moment since you return the count or 0 before you finish your loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think the actual question is to read two values and decide if it's two numbers or a char and a string. You can achieve this by reading two strings and parse them:

```
#include "mycount.hpp"
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::getline;
using std::isdigit;
using std::stoi;
using std::string;

int main() {
    string first;

    cin >> first;
    if (first.length() == 1 && !isdigit(first[0])) {
        // first is char and second is string
        cin.ignore();
        string second;
        std::getline(cin, second);
        cout << mycount(first[0], second) << '\n';
    else {
        // two numbers
        int second;
        cin >> second;
        cout << mycount(stoi(first), second) << '\n';
    }
}
```